# Issue creating multiple models from source layer in Threebox

Tags: three.js, mapbox, threebox

Currently trying to get to grips with Threebox.js and I'm run into an issue trying to create a wind turbine for each point on a layer. My code is as follows:

```js
function AddTurbineLayer()
{
    console.log("AddTurbineLayer");
    if(!renderedModels)
    {
        console.log("AddTurbineLayer - renderedModels");
        renderedModels = true;


        var options = {
            obj: './assets/Models/WindTurbineGLB-Blender.glb',
            type: 'glb',
            scale: 10,
            units: 'meters',
            rotation: { x: 90, y: 180, z: 0 }, //default rotation
        }

        app.map.addLayer({
            id: 'threebox-test-models',
            type: 'custom',
            renderingMode: '3d',
            layout: {
                visibility: 'none'
            },
            onAdd: function (m, mbxContext) {

                var source = app.map.queryRenderedFeatures({layers: ['buffer_images']});
                console.log(source);
                let promises = [];

                for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
                    var feature = source[i];
                    options.rotation = { x: 90, y: i * 10, z: 0 };

                    promises.push(new Promise((resolve) => { 
                      tb.loadObj(options, function (model) {
                          var turbine = model.setCoords(feature.geometry.coordinates);
                          tb.add(turbine);
                          resolve(true);
                      });
                    }));
                }

                Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                  console.log("All models loaded");

                  app.map.repaint = true;
                });
            },
            render: function (gl, matrix) {
                tb.update(); //update Threebox scene
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The method runs 5 seconds after the map has loaded or when the map is idle, whichever is first. What I'm expecting, since there are 4 points on the map corresponding to the 4 icons on the map, there should be 4 turbines next to each icon which it doesn't do.

Then to try and figure out how many it was creating I decided to set the Y rotation to be based on the index of the array, when doing this I was expecting 4 turbines rotating around the last point in the array. This didn't happen either and only rendered 2, I get the following result:

[image]

My question is, what am I missing to make this behaviour and why is it only rendering 2 turbines and not 4?

Edit 18/10:
Here's the console log, it contains all the four points on the map
[image]

Edit 19/10:
One thing I noticed when trying to use the Threebox example for rendering multiple models at once but changing it from using random coordinates to the ones from my layer.
[image]

Despite the fact that the variable `j` is defined in the same way as `source` it comes back as undefined. Is there something I'm missing with how JavaScript uses scopes? I've had a look at the types of scope and this should work

Comment: What does `console.log(source);` say?

Comment: I've attached an image

Comment: @Adam_R You need to change `for (var i=0;` into `for (let i=0;`.

Comment: Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30479554/3617380). TL;DR: `for (let i` creates new `i` for each loop iteration, while `for (var i` share the same `i` across all iteration. It makes no diff in iteration logic per se, UNTILL you pass the i into some closure/function, which is exactly what you did. For `var i` case, by the time your `tb.loadObj(cb)` callbacks actually get called, they all find `i == 4` because that's what `i++` ends up when the for-loop breaks.

Comment: I'm the owner of Threebox repo you are using. Can you log in the console `feature.geometry.coordinates` of the four objects?